# Derivation of $F=πB\sin θ$?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, textbook-erratum

I was searching for a formula for the magnetic force on a current-carrying conductor, and though I am accustomed to the formula $$F=IlB\sin θ$$ where $I=$ current, $l=$ length of conductor, $B=$ magnetic field strength and $θ$ is the angle between the conductor and the magnetic field lines).

I found another one in the following [link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/College_Physics/Book%3A_College_Physics_(OpenStax)/22%3A_Magnetism/22.08%3A_Magnetic_Force_on_a_Current-Carrying_Conductor). I read through the derivation of $F=πB\sin θ$, but I am still unsure how it was possible to conclude this.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi$ is a "badly chosen" label given it is not formally defined and it is not equal to $3.142....$ but rather equal to $Il$ where $I$ is the current and $l$ is the length of the conductor.

It might well be a typo where Il was mistaken for $\pi$?
Look at the text below Figure 22.8.2 where both versions of the equation for the force occur.